# Facebook updating

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, facebook

I am trying to update facebook from my Mac application i am working on. I am able to update status & links successfully. using the facebook api & documentation 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.setStatus/

But I want to update something like this. So how can I do this. I have used status.set, link.post but it is not looking like this. [image]

Comment: How does yours look? WHat have you tried?

Comment: yes I have tried using link.post & link.preview for image. But mine is not comming like this..in mine it is showing i have shared a link. But in this one there is nothing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this you'd use

```
link=http://www.example.com/
picture=http://www.example.com/icon.png
name=NinJump Deluxe
caption=I just got a score of 39101 in the castle level of NinJump Deluxe, an awesome new iPhone/iPod Touch game by Backflip Studios!
redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/
actions={"name": "Get NinJump Deluxe", "link": "http://www.facebook.com"}
```

Comment: this is  related to Graph API. But cant we do this using the old api http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/

Comment: I'd recommend staying away from the rest API as it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over how the status update looks, controlling images and more of that type, you should use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and request user permission for posting on their wall (think Facebook application).

Another possibility is just [implementing a Like-button in your application](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/), but then you're not as flexible in output.